# Strong Name Validation Failed

Tags: c#, c++-cli, code-signing

Two machines. Both with .NET 3.5 and the VS 2008 VC++ SP1 redistributables

A single exe which uses two signed DLLs, one in C++/CLI and one in C#

The exe loads and runs fine on one machine.

On the other, I get "Strong Name Validation Failed" on the C++ executable (HRESULT 0x8013141A)

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the supportedRuntimeVersion set correctly in the configuration section of the .exe.config?

Comment: Finally, this Link helped me: http://www.jarredcapellman.com/2013/2/25/monotouch-inside-visual-studio-2012-mscorlib-strong-name-validation-failed

Answer (score 57):

Open the command prompt as administrator and enter following commands:

```
reg DELETE "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\StrongName\Verification" /f
reg ADD "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\StrongName\Verification\*,*" /f
reg DELETE "HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\StrongName\Verification" /f
reg ADD "HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\StrongName\Verification\*,*" /f
```

Comment: Could you explain what exactly this does?

Comment: this will add the appropriate registry key manually for skipping strong name validation, if you can't run 'sn.exe -Vr <assembly>' cmd or if it doesn't work even after running that cmd.

Comment: These commands work in 2021 as well. I am not sure why microsoft docs ask for [different](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/disable-strong-name-bypass-feature#disable-the-strong-name-bypass-feature-for-all-applications) registry paths to update which does not work

Comment: Undertand doing this is a big security risk.  This allows any code published by anyone to run.  This should only be considered in a development environment and really only used as a litmus test to validate the problem.

Comment: These commands work in 2022

Comment: These commands work in 2023

Answer (score 19):

Open the command prompt **as administrator** and enter the following command:

> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\x64\sn.exe" -Vr <dllpath>

Pay attention that the argument are case sensitive.
Source with more details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/keithmg/archive/2012/03/20/strong-name-validation-failed-exception-from-hresult-0x8013141a.aspx

Comment: It should be noted that this doesn't really "fix" anything, it just disables the verification.

Answer (score 16):

You must use the 64-bit version of sn.exe on a 64-bit machine.  (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\x64\sn.exe)

Answer (score 9):

Is the one the code runs on a "development" machine where you might have run "sn.exe -Vr AssemblyName.dll" at some stage which would allow you to use a delay signed assembly as if it were fully signed. When you transfer the delay signed assembly to another machine and run it, it will fail strong name validation because it is not fully signed.

Comment: Is there a workaround other than running sn.exe on every other machine?

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I had the same issue with `Visual Studio 2015` and I already had signed the assembly.

I fixed it by this way: **Right click on the project which causes the issue -> "Properties" -> "Build" -> Change the value of the "Platform target" field.**

I had to change it from `Any CPU` to `x86` but I guess that in function of the project and the library which is failing, you should change its value to `x64`.

Answer (score 7):

If someone can't find 64-bit version of `sn.exe`, check here: 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools\x64\sn.exe`

Answer (score 5):

You might be able to bypass this on development by going into the project settings -> Signing -> and unchecking "Sign the assembly".

I ran into this today while debugging against a source code copy of the Entity Framework.

Answer (score 5):

The SN.EXE is Missing in Newer versions of Visual Studio. In Visual studio 2012,
we must use "Developer command prompt for Visual studio 2012". Then Run the command "sn".

Syntax:         sn -Vr *,2d58152b8e842be2

where  "2d58152b8e842be2" is the public key token shown in the Error message. Somehow this alone did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this today and stumbled across http://timgeerts.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/strong-name-validation-failed.html, which seems to be the solution.

Option 1) Turn off code coverage (in VS 2010, go to Test Settings -› Data and Diagnostics -› Untick the "Enabled" box next to Code Coverage).

Option 2) Add the signing key file to the code coverage configuration (in VS 2010, go to Test Settings -› Data and Diagnostics -› select Code Coverage and click on "Configure" at the top. This corresponds to the "keyFile" attribute for the CodeCoverage tag in the .testsettings file.)

In VS 2012, code coverage is enabled by default. It can be disabled through a .runsettings file with an appropriate exclusion. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159530.aspx for more information and a sample file. For option 2, although there doesn't seem to be an explicit setting available in the .runsettings file, the right thing seems to happen automatically with regard to signing (YMMV). However, if you're referencing a VS 2010 .testsettings file then it will need editing as above.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on Project → Properties → Build tab → Platform Target → Select "x64"

Answer (score 0):

I am working with VS.Net Ultimate 2012

and this solution helped me:

Right click on Project-> properties-> Build Tab-> switch Generate serialization assembly to off-> done

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by going to the Build menu (top pane) and say "Rebuild xxxProject.plugin" for that specific project only, contrary to building the entire solution.