# .net Could not load file or assembly MySql.Data. Strong name validation failed (0x8013141A)

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

**Error:**

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication4.exe
Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=8.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)
```

**Information:**

- Visual Studio 2015
- Windows 10 - x64
- C#
- MySQL 6.9.9

**Problem:**

I've made a class library using MySQL to run various queries to my online database.

After including the dll in my separate project, the only line of code I'm using is the following: (which it throws the exception on)

```
// Runs a simple select statement to find matches for 'John Doe' in my online MySQL database table... and stores results to a dataset
DataSet ds = MyDllNameSpace.Database.People.Load("John", "Doe");
```

**App.Config files:**

My dll project: (**I did NOT sign this project**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=8.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data></configuration>
```

My separate project: (**I did NOT sign this project**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>


  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.8.0" newVersion="8.0.8.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

**What I've searched/tried:**

- Made sure to use the same version of MySQL in both projects
- Put the dll to both my library and MySQL in the bin folder of my separate project and adding them as a reference
- Also tried adding both dlls of my library and MySQL to the separate project and selecting 'always copy'
- Changing around the App.config file (assuming the issue is in here?)
- Lastly, I tried signing both the dll project, and the project using the dll with the same password (checking sign the assembly). This also did nothing. :(

Thank you

Comment: **After hours and hours of trying to find out the problem... it turns out it was due to using the latest prelease version of MySql.Data in the Package Manager. After switching to the latest STABLE version, everything worked properly.**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried signing the project(s)? That may remove your error.

Maybe this link about your error will help: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/keithmg/2012/03/20/strong-name-validation-failed-exception-from-hresult-0x8013141a/

or this stackoverflow question:
[Strong Name Validation Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403731/strong-name-validation-failed)

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that. I tried signing the dll project, as well as the project that is using the dll (both with the same password). It's my first time signing a project, so hopefully I didn't do anything dumb to cause this. I will check over those links, but I think I've looked over those already. Thanks for your reply