# Azure Hybrid Connection Manager error install

Tags: azure, windows-server-2019

i am download from azure the last version of  Azure Hybrid Connection Manager msi and install on Microsoft Windows server 2019 or Windows 10.
The install not success why not start the service why?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you. It looks like the installer has an issue with a .dll, (Actually I saw your post in the Microsoft Forum giving you the basic instructions but not a solution to the issue).

If you check the Service Log it says:

> Service cannot be started. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Hosting.HybridConnectionManager.Tracing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)
> File name: 'Microsoft.Web.Hosting.HybridConnectionManager.Tracing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)
> The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
> MyComputer
> at Microsoft.HybridConnectionManager.HybridConnectionService.OnStart(String[] args)
> at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object state)

It mentioned "Strong name validation failed". The only solution I found about this is to disable the Strong Name Validation (WARNING NOTE: With this you are opening a security issue. But it can work while Microsoft fix the installer).

To do this just execute in a command screen with admin privileges.

```
reg DELETE "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\StrongName\Verification" /f
reg ADD "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\StrongName\Verification\*,*" /f
reg DELETE "HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\StrongName\Verification" /f
reg ADD "HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\StrongName\Verification\*,*" /f
```

You should be able to use this while a new version of the installer is released, then you have to restore the registry values to validate the strong names.

After running this commands, run the installer again and it should work.

Hope it helps. If it does, please mark this post as an answer.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I based my answer in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403731/strong-name-validation-failed. If you are using a development machine with a Microsoft SDK there are other ways to do this.